# How to specify discrete group through permutation cycles

Tags: permutation, group-theory

I would like to *define* a group of order 12 in Mathematica by giving a list of 12 elements in cycle notation,

$$ S = \{(e), (123), (132), (12)(45), (13)(45), (23)(45), (13), (23), (12), (45), (123)(45), (132)(45) \}$$

Is such a thing possible? If so, how? If I even so much as try to define a group using `Cycles` I get an error because as written above, the cycles do not have distinct elements.

I would like to know if there's a way to then do stuff like finding the character table of this group, using Mathematica.

---

For example, the following line

```
PermutationGroup[Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2}}]]
```

produces an error

```
Cycles::reppoint: Cycles[{{1,2,3},{1,3,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2}}] contains repeated integers.
```

By the way, this isn't even a specification of the full group. How does one specify **products** of cycles, like $(12)(45)$ or $(123)(45)$?

Comment: Could you include the code where you used `PermutationGroup[]` and `Cycles[]` to specify the group? It seems to me that you might have just made a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: You should be feeding a *list* of `Cycles[]` to `PermutationGroup[]`, e.g. `PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{1, 3, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}, {4, 5}}]}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cycles = {{{}}, {{1, 2, 3}}, {{1, 3, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 3}, {4, 5}}, 
 {{2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 3}}, {{2, 3}}, {{1, 2}}, {{4, 5}}, 
 {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 3, 2}, {4, 5}}};
pg = PermutationGroup[Cycles /@ cycles];
GroupOrder[pg]
```

> 12

```
GroupMultiplicationTable[pg] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
>  2 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 8 & 7 & 10 & 9 & 12 & 11 \\
>  3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 7 & 8 & 5 & 6 & 11 & 12 & 9 & 10 \\
>  4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 12 & 11 & 10 & 9 \\
>  5 & 6 & 9 & 10 & 1 & 2 & 11 & 12 & 3 & 4 & 7 & 8 \\
>  6 & 5 & 10 & 9 & 2 & 1 & 12 & 11 & 4 & 3 & 8 & 7 \\
>  7 & 8 & 11 & 12 & 3 & 4 & 9 & 10 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 6 \\
>  8 & 7 & 12 & 11 & 4 & 3 & 10 & 9 & 2 & 1 & 6 & 5 \\
>  9 & 10 & 5 & 6 & 11 & 12 & 1 & 2 & 7 & 8 & 3 & 4 \\
>  10 & 9 & 6 & 5 & 12 & 11 & 2 & 1 & 8 & 7 & 4 & 3 \\
>  11 & 12 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 1 & 2 \\
>  12 & 11 & 8 & 7 & 10 & 9 & 4 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 2 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
PermutationCycles /@ GroupMultiplicationTable[pg]
```

> {Cycles[{}], 
>    Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}}],
>    Cycles[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 7}, {6, 8}, {9, 11}, {10, 12}}],
>    Cycles[{{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 8}, {6, 7}, {9, 12}, {10, 11}}],
>    Cycles[{{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 9}, {4, 10}, {7, 11}, {8, 12}}],
>    Cycles[{{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 10}, {4, 9}, {7, 12}, {8, 11}}],
>    Cycles[{{1, 7, 9}, {2, 8, 10}, {3, 11, 5}, {4, 12, 6}}],
>    Cycles[{{1, 8, 9, 2, 7, 10}, {3, 12, 5, 4, 11, 6}}],
>    Cycles[{{1, 9, 7}, {2, 10, 8}, {3, 5, 11}, {4, 6, 12}}],
>    Cycles[{{1, 10, 7, 2, 9, 8}, {3, 6, 11, 4, 5, 12}}],
>    Cycles[{{1, 11}, {2, 12}, {3, 7}, {4, 8}, {5, 9}, {6, 10}}],
>    Cycles[{{1, 12}, {2, 11}, {3, 8}, {4, 7}, {5, 10}, {6, 9}}]}

```
 PermutationProduct[Cycles[{{1, 2}, {4, 5}}],  Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}}]]
```

> Cycles[{{1, 3}}]

Comment: Don't you want it to be ``cycles = {{{}}, {{1, 2, 3}}, {{1, 3, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 
     3}, {4, 5}}, {{2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 3}}, {{2, 3}}, {{1, 2}}, {{4,
      5}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 3, 2}, {4, 5}}};`` ?

Comment: @leastaction, yes; missed few elements in your list. Corrected now.

Comment: You might also be interested in `GroupMultiplicationTable[]` @least.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I am -- but can we re-express the elements in cycle form?